# How to save all the output in snowflake procedure?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have written a procedure wherein a variable has a select statement which is creating multiple update statements..
If I execute the variable it will give the query from select statement and if I execute the variable which has all the update statement list will it update everything as required??

I also want to know **how can I save all each update query's row count as there are more than 300 updates statements**

Comment: Please update the question to include a minimal code sample and desired output. To address the second part of the question, you can store the update counts in an array and insert them into a table in one statement to avoid single-row inserts.

Comment: Thanks @greg pavlik,I have checked and understood your multiple query procedure.. But my only concern here is how should I save all the update statement row count in that procedure

Comment: If you run your `update` from a `Statement` object, there is a method called `getNumRowsAffected` that tells you how many rows it updated:  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-api.html#getNumRowsAffected

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.